# How to import just two cells from CSV file to PHP

Tags: php, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file with lots of data in it, from which I create many different tables using 
PHP, specifying certain rows and columns.

However, I have a requirement for only showing two cells, A7 and A8. The code I currently use requires fields for table head and table data, which on this occasion I don't need.

What is the most effect way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function get_cell($cell, $row)
{
    $file = 'stuff.csv';

    $row = $row -1;
    // Reset the $row if it's negative.
    if($row < 0)
    {
        $row = 0;
    }
    $handle = fopen ($file, "r");
    $counter = 0;
    while (($csvline = fgetcsv($handle, 450,";")) != false)
    {
        if($counter == $row)
        {
            $new_array = array();
            $begin = 'a';
            foreach($csvline as $cellnr)
            {   
                $new_array[$begin] = $cellnr;
                $begin++;
            }
            echo $new_array[strtolower($cell)];
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}

get_cell('a', 1);
echo '<br>';
get_cell('b', 1);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and forgive me, I'm a novice at this. Where would I put the values for row 1, column 7 and 8. I realise I had it round the other way in my original question.

Comment: In this example you can use the function `get_cell()` just fill in the row for the first example and the column for the second one. For instance if you want B3 just use `get_cell(3, 'B')`. The function echoes it out. If you would want to use it to fill a `TD` or `TH` just use it like this. `echo '<td>'. get_cell(0, 'A') .'</td>';`

Comment: My apologies for some reason I had in minde .csv files started on row 0. I'll make two quick adjustments to the code.

Comment: Apologies, I'm still a little confused by it. The code above works, but displays the whole of the first row for me, and I cannot work out how to just show two columns? The end result will then be displayed in a table, two columns wide by 1 column deep.

Comment: Have you made sure that your csv file is delimited with ; or , check which one it is and make an adjustment to the code above. The 3rd parameter of fgetcsv is the delimiter. I thought you said you wanted to display certain cells not columns of a CSV file.

Comment: Ah-ha, my delimiter was a comma. So that's fixed that. I'm just struggling to put it into a table now. I tried your suggestion above, but do I need to add in TABLE and TR somewhere too? The end result should be a table with one row and two columns, populated by the two cells singled out above. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ah ok I think you formulated your question wrong.
Let me get back on this I think I know what you want to do.